# NP-hardness of partitioning into k sets

Tags: reference-request, partitions

Given a multiset $S$ of positive integers and a fixed positive integer $k$, can $S$ be partitioned into $k$ parts with equal sum?

For $k = 2$, this is the well-known Partition problem. For general $k$, this is described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiway_number_partitioning) as the "multiway number partitioning" problem, and it's claimed there that this problem is NP-hard for every fixed $k$. However, the reference provided there is not satisfactory because it is about a different problem. I also cannot find this problem in Garey and Johnson's "Computers and Intractability: A Guide to the Theory of NP-Completeness".

Is there a good reference for the NP-hardness of this problem?

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53745/5038, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/164884/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  If you post on the wrong site, you can delete the copy on the wrong site before posting on a new site.

Comment: @D.W. Can you please help delete whichever one you think is on the wrong site?

Comment: You have power to delete any question you have asked, but I can't delete a question on another site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reduction is simple, so you might not require a reference.

Given an instance for $k = 2$, simply add $p$ integers each of value $SUM/2$, where $SUM$ is the sum of all the elements in multiset $S$. The new instance has $k := p + 2$.

For $k = 2$, the $\mathsf{NP}$-hardness proof is already given on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Computational_hardness).